# Syntax if variable includes a specific string of text

Tags: spss

I was wondering if there was a syntax to select all account names that include a certain string of text.

For example, if I have a SPSS file that has 3 million account names, I'd want to look at only the account names that have a / TKS at the end. The account name could like like Stack Overflow / TKS.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `char.index` to check whether a string includes a specific substring.
So for example:

```
compute containsTKS=0.
if char.index(account_name,"/ TKS")>0 containsTKS=1.
execute.
```

You can then use `containsTKS` to `filter` or `select cases`.

Answer (score 1):

The solution eli-k provided checks if `/ TKS` is *inside* the `account_name`, at *any* position.
If you want to check if the `"/ TKS"` text is *at the end* of your `account_name`, you need a slightly changed syntax:

```
compute containsTKS=0.
if char.index(account_name,"/ TKS")=char.len(rtrim(account_name))-5 containsTKS=1.
execute.
```

Then, as eli-k mentioned, "You can then use `containsTKS` to `filter` or `select cases`."